# "can not resolve R" android studio

Tags: android-studio

Hola yo tengo este problema en todos mis proyectos en android studio y probe con "clear project" y 
con Tools" -> "Android" -> "Sync Project with Gradle Files".
Y el problema sigue, que otra solución me podrían sugerir por favor.

android.gradle(module)

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.diego.tpfinal"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
```

android.gradle(project)

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the [![Consola de android studio][1]][1]individual module build.gradle files
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualizada---- build.gradle(module)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Solución:**
Yo arregle mi problema con el siguiente video y con los comentarios de Elena previamente.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pw4jKsOU7go

Comment: Diego son varias posibles causas de tu problema incluso dentro de alguna clase podrias tener una referencia erronea de R. Indicas que es en todos los proyectos, reinicia Android Studio y revisa algun mensaje de error en la consola.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**El problema de no poder generar la clase `R.java` es debido generalmente a que existe un error en los recursos.**

Revisa alguna x roja que indica un problema o revisa en los mensajes.

Prueba con un  `Clean Project` >  `Build` , si esto no lo soluciona, seguramente mostrará cual es el problema.

actualización:

Tienes que revisar que tienes instalada la API 23, eso lo verificas en el Android SDK Manager.

[image]

y asegura dentro de tu build.gradle que tienes la versión que descargaste

[image]

Comment: Gracias Elena, si me aparece este error                          Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 8 cannot be smaller than version 9 declared in library [com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0] C:\Users\diego\AndroidStudioProjects\tpfinal\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-appindexing\8.1.0\AndroidManifest.xml
 Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms.appindexing" to force usage

Comment: No entiendo  la pregunta disculpa, si te referis en donde aparece ese error es en "messages grade build"

Comment: ok en tu Manifest.xml define minSdkVersion como 9.

Comment: Sigue el problema :/

Comment: recuerda clean  y Build y revisa nuevamente que error muestra.

Comment: A veces también cerrar el Android Studio y volverlo abrir, o reiniciar el computador de vez en cuando se limpia cosas que podrían afectar a la compilación.

Comment: @Elenasys ahi edite la pregunta y arregle unas cosas, creo que es algo del buildsdk pero estoy un poco perdido

Comment: @Webserveis reinicie el android studio y el problema sigue, gracias.

Comment: actualice mi respuesta en base a tu error, tienes que descargar el androis sdk version 23 .

Comment: @Elenasys gracias Elena, creo que el problema esta en la clase build.gradle en dependencias. Pero que deberia poner ahi? ya esta instalada la API 23, le di clean y rebuild project. Y sigue subrayando en rojo esas dependencias. Ah actualize la pregunta de nuevo.

Comment: @Elenasys Gracias lo solucione con el video que deje el link arriba, era lo que decías pero no entendía como solucionarlo.

Comment: Me alegra mucho Diego. Si esta la API 23 debes tener definida la versión correcta de las librerias, por ejemplo tengo buildToolVersion "23.1.1" y tambien las librerias del sdk son version 23.1.1 por ejemplo : compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'