# Mi proyecto no reconoce la clase R en Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Mi proyecto no reconoce la clase R, he buscado algunos videos y son viejos y no me funcionan. A continuancion dejare una foto del error:

Si alguien sabe alguna solucion me seria de gran ayuda, Gracias de antemano.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: refresca el gradle https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20815998/cant-find-sync-project-with-gradle-files-button-in-intellij-idea/21376913

Comment: checa todos los archivos xml, que no tengan errores, una vez corregidos ve a Build-rebuild project

Comment: Ya lo hice bro, y me sigue tirando el error

Comment: ¿Revisaste que todos tus layouts (archivos XML) son correctos, que no tienen error?

Comment: Si bro, solo me esta dando error el MainActivity.java

Comment: Como comenta A. Cedano debe existir un error , esta pregunta puede ser similar a : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/11900/can-not-resolve-r-android-studio/11901#11901

Comment: si vas sobre la R y apretas alt enter no te de ja importar nada?

Comment: Tenes que ir a la opcion rebuild

Comment: @edward1499 Puedes probar a darle a la opción `"Invalidate Caches / Restart"` en la pestaña `File` del menu de android studio, me ocurrió una vez y lo solucione de esa forma, también ocurre cuando creas un package en alguna otra parte del código, y debes importar la clase `R` de la principal.

Comment: Importe la clase asi import com.example.example.R; cambia el import por el nombre de tu paquete.